# f# how to filter mixed data type for a specific type

Tags: f#

I m trying to filter a mixed data type for a specific type, say float (ideally this would be dynamic though)

here my example:

```
let testobj = [8.0 , 1.0, "bla" ; 8.0 , 1.0, "bla"]

let testfun data = data |> List.filter (fun a -> 
      match a.GetType() with 
      | float -> a
      | _ -> 0.0)
```

now this should return [8.0 , 1.0, 0.0 ; 8.0 , 1.0, 0.0] for testobj but I m gettting an error that the function is of type bool

Comment: `testobj` is of type `(float * float * string) list`. Is that what you need, or it should be a list of objects of any types (`obj list`)?

Comment: its actually object[,] and I want the doubles which are all but first row and first two columns

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't what you want to do.

Seriously.

F# wants lists to be homogeneous and your list is not homogeneous.  `float` and `string` don't share a common base class so you're not going to get a list from it.

What F# wants you to do is to use a discriminated union for this. So if you have this type:

```
type Composite =
    | Num of float
    | Str of string
```

you can define your list like this:

```
let data = [ Num(8.0); Num(1.0); Str("bla"); Num(8.0); Num(1.0); Str("bla") ]
```

and from there you can pattern match on the types and your function looks like this:

```
let testfun d = d |> List.map (fun a ->
    match a with
    | Num x -> a
    | _ -> Num(0.0) )

data|> testfun |> printfn "%A"
```

And the output will be:

```
 [Num 8.0; Num 1.0; Num 0.0; Num 8.0 ; Num 1.0 ; Num 0.0;]
```

If you want floats in the end and not Composites, do this:

```
let testfun1 d = d |> List.map (fun a ->
    match a with
    | Num x -> x
    | _ -> 0.0 )
```

which sheds the composite type.  And everything (and I mean everything) in that code is type strong and type-safe.

From a real-world maintenance point of view, I would eschew the `_` case in the matches and instead use all my types, reasoning that if I extend Composite to include another type I would want the compiler to scream at me and look at each function that uses it rather than silently assuming that 0.0 or Num(0.0) is really what I wanted.

For example, if I added integers to that type, this would do exactly the wrong thing if I wanted to sum the contents of a list of composites.

Given that you're stuck/hell-bent on a weakly-typed data set, then you want something like this:

```
let testfun2 d = d |> Array.map (fun (a:Object) ->
    match a with
    | :? float as x -> x
    | _ -> 0.0
    )

let data:Object[] = [|8.0; 1.0; "bla"; 8.0; 1.0; "bla"|]
data |> testfun2 |> printfn "%A"
```

which will print what you expect. Note that I'm using proper Array syntax and **not** list syntax.

**However** this is feeling really wonky for F#. See how I have to adorn `a` and `d` with types? In my previous code, the language can figure it all out. If I don't adorn either, I get compiler errors because we're really going against the grain of the type system.

If *I* were you, I would be inclined to do something like this first:

```
let recast d = d |> Array.map (fun (a:Object) ->
    match a with
    | :? float as x -> Num x
    | :? string as x -> Str x
    | _ -> raise (ArgumentException("that was unexpected: " + a.GetType().Name))
    )
```

which turns this into an Array of Composite which is now type strong. If you tack on `|> Array.toList` after the `Array.map`, you get a list (if you want that).

Comment: thank you. Issue is I get a object[,] from a DB as this contains 1 header row and two string columns and rest doubles and I wanted to filter for the doubles only.

Comment: What you've declared above is a list of tuple. Do you have an array of object?

Comment: yes object[9000,500], the tuple was just a test on how to filter